# Find all Change Combinations (money) in OCaml

Tags: optimization, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I have a some OCaml code that finds all combinations of change given a change amount.  I have most of the code working, however I am not able to figure out how this recursive function will actually return the possible change combinations.

```
let change_combos presidents = 
  let rec change amount coinlist =  match amount with 
    |0 -> [[]] (*exits when nothing*)
    |_ when (amount < 0) -> [] (*exits when less than 0*)
    |_ -> match coinlist with
    |[] -> [] (*Returns empty list, exits program*)

(*h::f -> something, using [25;10;5;1] aka all change combinations...*)
(*using recursion, going through all combinations and joining lists returned together*)

let print_the_coin_matrix_for_all_our_joy enter_the_matrix =
print_endline (join "\n" (List.map array_to_string enter_the_matrix));;
```

Thanks for the help, let me know if I need to clarify something :)

Comment: This code is too fragmentary to say much about it. The general answer to what I think you're asking is that a function is defined by an expression (something with a value). This value is what is returned by the function. But this is probably not helpful :-) Perhaps you could ask something more specific.

Comment: So I think I should be able to do my joins like this:
    let join concat all_my_lists = 
    List.fold_left (fun x y -> x ^ concat ^ y) "" all_my_lists;;  
      
    let array_to_string array =
    join ", " (List.map string_of_int array);;  
  
But not sure how to actually call the recursive function to return all combinations of the "change"...
Hopefully that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Bit of advice, when you are nesting `match … with` constructs, uses parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit confusing what you're looking for. I believe that you want to generate a list of all the combinations of a list? You should think about the recursion and how to generate the individual elements. Start with the input type, and how you'd generate successive elements by reducing the problem space.

```
let rec generate lst = match lst with
  | []   -> []
  | h::t -> [h] :: (List.map (fun x -> h::x) (generate t)) @ (generate t)
```

If the list is `[]` there are no combinations. If we have an element we generate all combinations without that element and base our construction on that assumption. The components fall into place at this point. Concatenate the list of combinations of `t` with the combinations of `t` and `h` `cons`'d onto each and a singleton of `h`.